# Show/Hide element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have element (div),

Named: element1, element2, element3

By default : element1 is visible, element2 is visible, element3 is hidden

Here is the code I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#element3').hide();
        $('#element1').click(function () {
            $('#element3').toggle(400);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I use the code above to make element3 is visible when I click on element1.

My question

1. How to make element2 is hidden and element 3 is visible when I click
   on element1?
2. How can I revert back to default after I click again in element1?

Comment: why don't you read the manual? (it wasn't my down vote)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#element3').hide();
    $('#element1').click(function () {
        $('#element3').toggle(400);
        $('#element2').toggle(400);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LKQ53/)

Comment: I'm going to have to downvote. in jQuery 1.9, they have moved away from `.toggle()` as it has been removed.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy they have removed it for the click toggle, but not the show hide toggle

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: The show/hide version of `toggle` is alive and well: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ You're thinking of the every-other-click `toggle`: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @BlakePlumb Very well, I redact my downvote. This solution will work.

Comment: This is what I looking for,..sorry for my stupid question coz I am very newbie in jquery/javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can use below solution for your problem:

As per your requirement when you will click `element1` then `element3` and `element2` will toggle respectively in every alternate click. Below code should solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#element3').hide();
    $('#element1').click(function () {
        $('#element3').toggle(400);
        $('#element2').toggle(400);
    }); 
});
```

Also refer to [this link](http://aspdotnetraining.blogspot.in/2013/11/jquery-hide.html) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#element1').click(function(){
         $('#element3').toggle();
         $('#element2').toggle();
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, the same other than the other answer being right and this one being a no-op (`document` shouldn't be in quotes).